# manage timezones JS difference of two hours

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

frontend side I send axios this date away:

```
Mon Jun 13 2022 18:29:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
```

because the backend (laravel 8.x) side saves me the usual one as follows:

```
2022-06-13 16:29:00
```

I wish he would save me 18:29 and not 16:29

how can i handle this? i can't install libraries like moment.js

Comment: Check the time zone in the background, by default it is the standard time zone (GMT)

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what i should do, checking the date in JS is GMT + 0200

Answer (score 2):

This will likely be due to your app timezone being set to UTC. I personally would recommend storing everything in UTC and converting that for display purposes on the front end.

However, if you must store them in the same format, you'll need to set the timezone in `config/app.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC', <--- Change this to your timezone eg: Africa/Cairo
```

[Select the correct timezone from this list.](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/gmt+2#:%7E:text=GMT%2B02%20is%20a%20time,months%20(Daylight%20saving%20time).)

[image: Timezones available for GMT+0200]

**Don't forget to run `php artisan config:clear` to ensure your timezone configuration changes are being used.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows:

```
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds).toString().slice(0, 24);
```

can you do better?